# file recovery tools questions

Tags: files

I'm curious about these recovery tools, I got 3 questions.
When I used TestDisk this is what I received.

> TestDisk 7.0, Data Recovery Utility, April 2015 Christophe GRENIER
>    http://www.cgsecurity.org
>
> Disk /dev/sda - 160 GB / 149 GiB - CHS 19457 255 63
>
> The harddisk (160 GB / 149 GiB) seems too small! (< 253 GB / 235 GiB)
>   Check the harddisk size: HD jumpers settings, BIOS detection...
>
> The following partitions can't be recovered:
>        Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors    Linux                 9416 118 47 28612 151 19  308385792
>
> > Linux                 9417  91 19 28613 123 54  308385792    Linux                 9417 221 21 28613 253 56  308385792    Linux                 9418  63
> >     54 28614  96 26  308385792    Linux                 9421 209  5 28617
> >     241 40  308385792    Linux                 9422  84  7 28618 116 42 
> >     308385792    Linux                 9423 121 43 28619 154 15  308385792
> >     Linux                 9428 212  1 28624 244 36  308385792    Linux
> >     9430  27  6 28626  59 41  308385792    Linux                11352  39
> >     16 30548  71 51  308385792
>
> [ Continue ]
>   ext4 blocksize=4096 Large_file Sparse_SB Recover, 157 GB
>   / 147 GiB

2. PhotoRec is moving the files or copying?
3. SafeCopy will keep the folder name and files name? Or it's the same with PhotoRec that will rename the files and scrumble it?

Answer (score 0):

**PhotoRec** can identify a data chunk 'on the disk' even when there is no pointer to it in the file system (which happens, when the file is deleted, and which can happen, when the file system is damaged). PhotoRec will copy from these data to files in another drive.

See the following link and links from it, if you want more details,

[Repair the partition table and file system of a pendrive](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13409986#post13409986)